# How can a third party sign and validate a transaction that does not involve money?

Tags: solidity, sendsignedtransaction

As a beginner in Solidity, I'm trying to figure out how to do someting with the things I know, but maybe there are other tools that would solve better my needs.

Do Approve() global function  works only for transactions that involve value requests?
I mean, can I use Approve() to just give permission to register some information that I validated on the blockchain?

Let's say a visitor fills a form in my site and he wants to save that in the blockchain. He is the smart contract caller, he will pay the gas fee. Can I use any source (like Approve) to sign and confirm that such information was made in my site and I validate it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is not global "approve()", it is only specific to tokens like ERC20, ERC721, and it only work for approving transfers by the approved operator. Although it should be easy to implement similar feature for any contract.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying.
Would you recommend any content to read about this feature I mentioned?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't read anything about that particular issue. In general you could read the [EIP-20](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20), [EIP-721](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721) also check their github issues for the discussion details.